# How to solve Authorization header using Bearer Angular x OpenAI

Tags: node.js, angular, http-post, openai-api

I have this error which appear and disappear time to time, but those days that's every day :
`You didn't provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in an Authorization header using Bearer auth (i.e. Authorization: Bearer YOUR_KEY), or as the password field (with blank username) if you're accessing the API from your browser and are prompted for a username and password. You can obtain an API key from https://beta.openai.com.`

And so my Angular application doesn't work properly anymore.
Here is my call to the API :

```
  try {
    const body = {
      "model": "text-davinci-003",
      "prompt": ask,
      "temperature": 0.7,
      "max_tokens": 10000,
      "top_p": 1,
      "frequency_penalty": 0.0,
      "presence_penalty": 0.0
    }
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${environment.OPENAI_SECRET_KEY}`
    });
    const completion: any = await this.http.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", body, { headers }).toPromise();
    this.response = completion.choices[0].text as string;
    this.articleService.updateArticle(this.createdArticleId, this.generateText(this.response));
    console.log(completion);
    console.log(completion.choices[0].text);
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
    this.connectToAPI(ask, true);
  }
```

Before I was using the properly method with npm install of openai packages, but today I changed for this way to have the APIKEY in the header, but that didn't help...

If someone have an idea, I would be very great full, because I already watch many link on Google, but nothing did !

Answer (score 0):

Check if there was any extra encoding characters in your open AI key. This happens especially if you are copy  and pasting from a rich text editor to a plain text one.